# Python TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.4

My code:

```
for i in range( 3.3, 5 ):
        print( i )
```

The above code have to print:

> 3.300000
>
> 4.300000

but the interpreter of Python 3.4.0 printed the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: `range()` works with integers, not fractional values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range()` works with integers not floats, but you can build your own range generator which will do what you want:

```
def frange(start, stop, step=1):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step
```

`for i in frange(3.3, 5)` will give you the desired result.

Note though, that `frange` will, unlike `range` but like `xrange`, return a generator rather than a list.