# Python Simpson's Rule Float object error

Tags: python-3.x

I am having problem with the simpsons rule. It is saying float object cannot be interpreted as an integer in for i in range(1, (n/2) + 1):

```
def simpson(f, a, b, n):
h=(b-a)/n
k=0.0
x= a + h
for i in range(1, (n/2) + 1):
    k += 4*f(x)
    x += 2*h

x = a + 2*h
for i in range(1, n/2):
    k +=2*f(x)
    x += 2*h
return (h/3)*(f(a)+f(b)+k)
```

result=simpson(lambda x:x, 0, 1, 4)
print (result)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355608/python-typeerror-float-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

`n / 2` returns a float in Python 3, while `range` only works with integers. You need to use integer division (`//`):

`range(1, (n // 2) + 1)`.

Comment: Ok i will give it a try

Comment: It worked thank you. I used the second method. So can you explain me how this first one works. i mean do i have to import any function before using this because when i tried the first function its is saying that the floor function is not defined.

Comment: @PemaChidaSherpa Indeed, in order to use `floor` you need to import it: `from math import floor`. I removed it from my answer as it is easier to simply use `//`.